# What programming techniques or topics should one master to do well in Google Code Jam?

Tags: c

In this year's Google Code Jam I couldn't solve a single problem of the qualifying round. [This](http://ideone.com/Gv2rfH) (full code at the bottom) is what i came up with to solve the [Fair and Square](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2270488/dashboard#s=p2) problem. And, it was judged to be incorrect, twice.

And, it's agonizingly demoralizing. I intend to change this scenario in the next Google Code Jam. I know one must practice(a lot!) to become better programmer and it takes years to become an expert. I believe i am ready to give that much effort. But, one can easily be overwhelmed by the size of the list of things to master.So, my question is that, **Can a learning path be devised so that one can identify and master the skills necessary to perform better in Google Code Jam or similar online contests? If yes, then what would that be?**

This path should allow one to master easier techniques first and then move on to harder ones as if the difficulty level was gradually increasing.

This is  my (wrong) solution of the Fair and Square problem

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h> 
int sqrRoot(double numberToCheck);
int isPalindrome(int numToCheck);


int main(void)
{
int i=0,j=0,cases=1,steps=0,low=0,high=0,isSquare=0,count=0,bit=0;
scanf("%d", &steps);

while (cases<=steps)
{
    scanf(" %d %d", &low, &high );
    for (j=low;j<=high;j++)
    {
        isSquare = sqrRoot(j);
        if (isSquare == 1)
        {
            bit = isPalindrome(j);
            if (bit==1)
            {
                count ++;
                //printf("\n wowowo# %d", j);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Case #%d: %d \n", cases,count);
    count = 0;
    bit = 0;
    cases++;
}

return 0;
}

int sqrRoot(double numberToCheck)
{

double result = sqrt(numberToCheck);
int y=0;
y = result;
 if (result == y)
 {

    return 1;
 }

 else
 {
    return 0;
 }
}


int isPalindrome(int numToCheck)
{
  int n=0,rev=0;
  double dig=0.0;
  n = numToCheck;

  while(numToCheck>0)
 {
   dig = numToCheck % 10;
       rev = rev * 10 + dig;
       numToCheck = numToCheck / 10;
 }

  if (n==rev)
 {
   return 1;
 }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems, given your description of there being such a long and intimidating list of skills to learn, that the best approach would be to only indirectly prepare for this competition and directly focus on learning as much as possible about computer science.  Being somewhat of an intermediate myself (and constantly striving to learn more), I can say that the periods of time when I have learned the most have been when I have sought not to acquire status (e.g. by winning awards) but honestly tried to emulate masters of the craft.  In the case of computer science, reading books by and attempting to reproduce the code produced by people like Peter Norvig (through his books and MOOC courses), for example, has led to hard earned but significant improvement in my skill.  I would say that above all else, such a strategy will allow you to improve to be able to succeed in competitions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to master Algorithms and Data Structures. There is one book that you can read online for free that I highly recommend: [Algorithms by Dasguspta](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms.html).

[Coursera.org has some courses](https://www.coursera.org/courses?orderby=upcoming&search=algorithms&cats=cs-theory) on this too. Sedgewick's is really good and [his book](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) is a nice addition to any bookshelf.

You can also practice with ACM problems or TopCoder, which also provides some [good tutorials](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index&module=Static)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert of algorithmic contests, but they ask you to do a work which is very different from real-world algorithmic problem solving. First, they often require an exact solution, where in real-life, an approximation may often be a very good choice. It simplify the validation: only one output is possible. Also, many hard problems became trivial if you can solve them by approximation. The second difference is that the organizer have to be sure that the points awarded for a problem are related to the difficulty of the problem. The problem must not have a trivial solution, and must require some work to be solved. This means that most of the problems are variants of a well-known problem, and the competitors must find how to adapt the usual algorithms to this problem. This way, one can judge how fast and well they adapted those algorithms.

For you, this means, that you have to know the usual optimization algorithms. Fortunately, there are books about them. Unfortunately, i don't know them. (I mainly learn them at the university) If you want to maximize your chances, you better have to work with these general algorithms:

- Pathfinding (Dept-first, Breath-first, Best-first, Dijkstra, A*)
- Dynamic programming
- Branch & Bound
- Dived & conquer
- Constraint programming
- Graph algorithms
- Perhaps [Flow network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network), but not sure you will need it

Those subjects overlap, and it's not easy in general to find which one will be useful. Now, this is only the theory. Like i said, the difficulty is to adapt them to the problem you have. And for this, you can only train, a lot. Training is also required as it will help you to know how to implement them fast and efficient. There are many ways to write these algorithms and with the experience you will know them (google will help) and know how to choose them. Of course, you can't start google code jam, look at some problem and say... "hmm... it remember me some problem i read in a book" You would lost too much time trying to implement it for the first time. This is also a big difference with real-world algorithmic.

Anyway, there are many other competitions. You should try them if you fulfill the requirements. It is usually fun and interesting.

Your solution is the most simple we can find about the Fair and Square problem. Of course, it's not enough: you always have to find a better than first solution. I believe yours is wrong in the isSquare function. Floating point arithmetic add small imprecisions which can alter very simple tests like the one you wrote.

The cost of your algorithm come from the number of numbers you test. These numbers may be huge (and by the way your code won't work for these huge numbers as they can't be stored in the usual 32 bits integers of C) and iterating through them might take an eternity. To improve that, you can directly iterate through the square roots. If you iterate `r` from `sqrt(A)` to `sqrt(B)`, then you are sure that the `r*r` are all the squares from `A` to `B`. Thus you don't have to test if their square root is an integer, and you have much less numbers to test.

This idea is very classical: reduce the size of the space to be iterated. You can further improve the algorithm by only iterating the roots which are palindromes. Fair and square roots also have some mathematical property, but i was too lazy to prove it, so i didn't look for another improvement. This is the final remark about your question: you may need basic mathematical knowledge to solve some of the problem. Usually, algorithmic skill is also the ability to prove the algorithms you use.